# Python multiple operate on multiple concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Hi I'm coming from Java development world where multiple futureTasks could have dependency relationships with nice interfaces. I start to use ThreadPoolExecutor in python, I'm looking for something like this

```
def getSomething():
    return 'Hello'

def combine(r1, r2):
    return r1 + r2

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
future1 = executor.submit(getSomething())
future2 = executor.submit(getSomething())
# assume the syntax
merge(future1, future2 -> combine(future1Result, future2Result)).result()
```

In the example code above, the `combine` function takes the output of these 2 futures and performs some operations (in practical it would be more complex). It's only after all the future result returned the `combine` would be executed.

I did researches on `as_completed` and `wait` methods provided, but one big con is it only returns the final result when future is done but forget the caller information, you'll need to use a dictionary to remember the future to its caller mapping.